# Puppet: Pass variables from Puppet agent to master?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to configure a selection of servers using a Puppet agent/master configuration.

My problem is this will include configuring an Apache virtual host for each server, as such I'd like to use the agent's unique hostname within the configuration file which is downloaded from the master.

Is there a way to pass "variables" from the Puppet agent to the Puppet master, or alternatively, is there a way for configurations to "inherit" each other so that I can write a specific custom virtual host configuration for each host, but otherwise all other directives are the same between hosts?

Comment: @FelixFrank No I haven't, I only know what I've learnt messing with Puppet in VMs. However I ended up sidestepping my issue by creating different nodes for each server, and then moving anything common to all servers into a class which is called in each node configuration. All custom configuration is done within the node / in a class dedicated to that node.

Comment: Have you finished Puppet's Learning VM course? What parts of the official documentation have you consulted, or what other research have you done?

Comment: Your solution is *kind of* how it's done, but there are some best practices that will make things easier. Do use the learning VM. Look at the Roles and Profiles pattern. There are even some good books available.

Comment: I _may_ be misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish, but any reason not to use the global $::hostname fact in the Apache virtual host configuration template?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Please flag my comment if it was indeed useful.